# classification and clustering of tweets

Tags: python, twitter, classification, jupyter, data-preprocessing

I am trying to implement classification and clustering of tweets and also using jupyter notebook and getting error while running this:

```
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
punctuation = list(string.punctuation)
stop.update(punctuation)
w_tokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer()

# clean the set of words
            
def furnished(text):
    final_text = []
    for i in text.split():
        if i.lower() not in stop:
            word = lemmatizer.lemmatize(i)
            final_text.append(word.lower())
    return " ".join(final_text)





the error i am getting is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-a9108abcd516> in <module>()
----> 1 nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
      2 tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
      3 lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
      4 stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
      5 punctuation = list(string.punctuation)
    enter code here

NameError: name 'en_core_web_sm' is not defined.
```

Can somebody please let me know where i am going wrong in this?

Comment: Did you `import en_core_web_sm`?

Comment: yes i did, still i am getting error : NameError: name 'RegexpTokenizer' is not defined @fsimonjetz

Comment: Did you `from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer`? Look, you need to copy the `import` statements from wherever you got this code, too. Otherwise your next question will be for the `NameError: name 'stopwords' is not defined`.

Comment: okay got it, i imported it before but there was a spelling error, now it worked :)